# The lines on my scatterplot for ANCOVA results doesn't look right, personal error or model error?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, regression-coefficients, ancova

I ran an ANCOVA model, to test the effect of treatment on the relationship between two continuous variables (elephant number and plant density) - please see more details in my last question ([What statistical model can incorporate my categorical variable (2 levels) and 2 continuous variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445346/what-statistical-model-can-incorporate-my-categorical-variable-2-levels-and-2)) but when visualizing my results on a scatterplot something isn't quite right.
Here are my ANCOVA summary results:

```
lm(formula = eledens ~ treat * plants, data = elemice)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-7.102 -2.715  0.264  1.814  9.235 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value    Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              8.3028     1.8952   4.381 0.000097820 ***
treatMice added         -0.7066     2.7105  -0.261    0.795810    
plants                   0.7368     0.1232   5.978 0.000000743 ***
treatMice added:plants  -0.6840     0.1613  -4.241    0.000148 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.856 on 36 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7393,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7176 
F-statistic: 34.04 on 3 and 36 DF,  p-value: 0.0000000001308
```

And here is my plotting code trying to visualize the result:

```
plot(eledens~plants, data=elemice, type="n", xlab="Plant Density", ylab="Elephant Density")
points(elemice$plants[elemice$treat=="Control"], elemice$eledens[elemice$treat=="Control"], col="skyblue3", pch=16)
points(elemice$plants[elemice$treat=="Mice added"], elemice$eledens[elemice$treat=="Mice added"], col="salmon", pch=16)
abline(fit.mice$coefficients[1:2], col="skyblue3")
abline(fit.mice$coefficients[1]+fit.mice$coefficients[3],fit.mice$coefficients[2], col="salmon")
new.x <- rep(seq(min(elemice$plants), max(elemice$plants), len=100),2)
new.s <- rep(c("Control","Mice added"), each=100)
pred <- predict(fit.mice, new=data.frame(plants=new.x, treat=new.s), interval="conf")
pred <- data.frame(pred, treat=new.s, plants=new.x)
head(pred)
lines(new.x[1:100],pred[1:100,"lwr"],lty=2, col="skyblue3")
lines(new.x[1:100],pred[1:100,"upr"],lty=2, col="skyblue3")
lines(new.x[101:200],pred[101:200,"lwr"],lty=2, col="salmon")
lines(new.x[101:200],pred[101:200,"upr"],lty=2, col="salmon")
legend("topleft", pch=16, col=c("skyblue3","salmon"), legend=c("Control","Mice added"))
```

As you can see below (see output graph) the fitted lines from the coefficients look a bit odd, so does this mean my model is incorrect? Or have I assigned the coefficients incorrectly in the coding? I am fairly new to R coding, so advice on interpreting this would be much appreciated.

[image: Effect of treatment on the relationship between elephant number and plant density]

Comment: Oh that was a genuine mistake, didn't notice that. I ran into some issues earlier and was halfway through adding a new graph to show the commenter when I realized I'd made an error in the code and it wasn't necessary. I must have deleted the original graph accidentally in the process. I will re-add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be misunderstanding the output from your model.
In your code, the line:

```
abline(fit.mice$coefficients[1:2], col="skyblue3")
```

plots a line with the correct intercept, but the wrong slope. `fit.mice$coefficients[1`] is the intercept, but `fit.mice$coefficients[2]` is the estimate for `treat` in the `Mice added` group, hence this is an offset to the intercept for the `Mice added` group. What you want for the slope in the `Control` group is simply the estimate for `plants` which is `fit.mice$coefficients[3]`. So:

```
abline(fit.mice$coefficients[1], fit.mice$coefficients[3] , col="skyblue3")
```

Then to plot the line for the `Mice added` group, the intercept will be the global intercept plus the estimate for `treat` and the slope will be the estimate for `plants` plus the interaction term. So:

```
abline(fit.mice$coefficients[1] + fit.mice$coefficients[2], fit.mice$coefficients[3] + fit.mice$coefficients[4], col="salmon")
```

Comment: Ah yes I see the error now! Revised the code with your suggestions and everything is now looking much better. Thanks again Robert, really appreciate the help.